# Oracle query performance when filtering results

Tags: oracle-11g

I am currently working on a query for a front end application, which is experiencing weird performance issues when filters are applied on large sets of data. Here is [a link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d0c4/5/0) to an SQLFiddle of the simplified query.

The query is executing in about 1-2 seconds when fetching all rows. (limited only by rownum) A similar performance can be observed when filtering by amounts above a certain threshold (e.g. total > 1000). However, when filtering below a threshold (e.g. available < 1000) the query is taking forever to calculate the results.

As a general note all related table columns are indexed.

Is there perhaps a better way to perform the calculations shown in the example?

Comment: There are too many SELECT queries in the SELECT clause. Ideal way to write such a query is with Oracle analytical functions Using Windowing clauses. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ident_account,ident_instrument,
        nvl(available, 0) + nvl(reserved, 0) + nvl(restrctd,0) AS total,
        nvl(available, 0) AS available,nvl(reserved, 0) AS reserved,nvl(restrctd, 0) AS restrctd,
        validfrom, minvaliduntil as validuntil
   FROM (
         SELECT h.ident_account, h.ident_instrument, h.validfrom, h.validuntil,
                rank() over(partition by h.ident_account, h.ident_instrument,IDENT_BALANCEGROUP order by h.validfrom desc) as rnk,
                sum(case when IDENT_BALANCEGROUP = 1 
                         then h.amount
                         else 0 end) over(partition by h.ident_account, h.ident_instrument,IDENT_BALANCEGROUP order by h.validfrom desc
                                          range between current row
                                                    and (nvl(validuntil,validfrom+1) - validfrom) following) as available,
                sum(case when IDENT_BALANCEGROUP = 2 
                         then h.amount
                         else 0 end) over(partition by h.ident_account, h.ident_instrument,IDENT_BALANCEGROUP order by h.validfrom desc
                                          range between current row
                                                    and (nvl(validuntil,validfrom+1) - validfrom) following) as reserved,
                sum(case when IDENT_BALANCEGROUP = 3
                         then h.amount
                         else 0 end) over(partition by h.ident_account, h.ident_instrument,IDENT_BALANCEGROUP order by h.validfrom desc
                                          range between current row
                                                    and (nvl(validuntil,validfrom+1) - validfrom) following) as restrctd,
                min(validuntil) over(partition by h.ident_account, h.ident_instrument order by h.validfrom desc
                                          range between current row
                                                    and (nvl(validuntil,validfrom+1) - validfrom) following) as minvaliduntil,
                h.amount,b.ident_balancegroup
           FROM holdings h INNER JOIN balancetype b ON h.ident_balancetype = b.ident_balancetype
        )
  WHERE rnk = 1;
```